# JQuery Cycle plugin - IE Transparency issue, who can help?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

I am using the JQuery Cycle plugin to cycle threw a bunch of DIV's, each DIV represents a weddings dress, with a pic, description and accessories etc.

All works fine in FF and Chrome, but in IE 6/7 there is a bug with the transparent .pngs. Each time the cycle switches DIV's a strange black fuzzy border is added to the pngs, this is extremely ugly.

I have read other posts which suggest converting the images to jpg's but the sites design elements wont permit this.

Here is a test url to demonstrate what I mean - http://fi-testing.co.uk/clients/cavendish/v2/wedding-dresses.html

A similar post on this site suggests using unitpng to target each image individually but I'm not sure how to edit the JS to do this.

Can anyone help me solve this please, the site is due to be launched soon.

Comment: It's more of IE6's Transparency issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE 6 I don't see any black fuzzy thing, but there's a missing image called clear.gif overlaid on every wedding dress photo.

The address of the image is:

http://fi-testing.co.uk/clients/cavendish/img/clear.gif

This image is not added to the markup in Firefox, so maybe it's one of those fixes meant to unfuck IE 6. Start looking into it.

Comment: Thanks, this may have just been my issue, I was linking to the wrong image folder. Ill try it out. Thanks for your prompt reply